# SQL query does not recognise derived table

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, derived-tables

So I've made a simple SQL query:

```
SELECT companyname
FROM works w1, (
                SELECT companyname,sum(salary) AS sumsal
                FROM works
                GROUP BY companyname
               ) w2
WHERE
w1.companyname=w2.companyname
```

it works fine so far but then I add the following line in the where clause:

```
AND w2.sumsal=(SELECT MIN(w2.sumsal)
               FROM w2);
```

I get:

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'companydb.w2' doesn't exist
```

I'm using MySQL 8.0.

Comment: What exactly do you want the query to show? The company that pays the lowest sum of salaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before answering the question, you are using `WHERE` instead of [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) for joining the tables, and join the tables using the company name instead of the row ID / primary key. It's better use [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) with row ID when joining tables (if your are using the company name as the primary key you really have to add to add a row ID and use it instead as the key).

Regarding your question, the problem is that the subquery `w2` can't be used in the right part of the `SELECT` because is out of scope, but you can use a [Common Table Expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) to create a "temporary view" that can be used in any part of the query. Then you can use two methods for getting the result:

Using `MIN()`:

```
with sums as (select companyname, sum(salary) AS sumsal
  from works
  group by companyname
)
select *
from sums
where sumsal=(select min(sumsal) from sums)
```

Using [`EXISTS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html):

```
with sums as (select companyname, sum(salary) AS sumsal
  from works
  group by companyname
)
select *
from sums
where not exists (select * from sums s2 where s2.sumsal<sums.sumsal)
```

I have created [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f52b926b678e337be54afabe07a354ab) for testing it online, there I have used `JOIN` with the company Id instead of the name as an example of how you can use that.